# Trying to get VLOOKUP to get data from a table array on another workbook where the worksheet name is variable

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I currently pull data in from 4 workbooks using the INDIRECT function, the formula is as follows,
=INDIRECT("'[" & $AE$1 & "]" & $AA$13 &"'!" & $AI$1)

$AE$1 contains the workbook name.
$AA$13 contains the worksheet name.
$AI$1 contains the cell ref.

This works fine BUT the workbooks all need to be open for the main book to display the results!

I have looked at VLOOKUP to do the same BUT cannot find a way to use the cell values within the table array of VLOOKUP. The only cell value I really need is for the worksheet name as I have up to 70 worksheets in each of the workbooks.

I tried using INDIRECT with VLOOKUP which looks like,

=VLOOKUP(E22,INDIRECT("'[" & $AE$1 & "]" & $AA$13 & "'!" & $AI$1),2,FALSE)

This does work but again using the INDIRECT function takes me back to the workbooks having to be open!

Perhaps I need to use a Pivot Table but not sure if I would still have the same issues!

Using both Excel 2007 & 2010

Any and all help appreciated.
Thanks
Stuart

Comment: Are you trying to pull data and have it pull while the other books are closed? Because you can't do that.

Comment: External references to CLOSED workbooks do not work with the [INDIRECT function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx) as clearly stated in the description. For closed workbook functionality you need VBA to open the workbook and get the value or possibly the `INDIRECT.EXT` from the *MoreFunc* add-on. I have a clean copy of [MoreFunc here](http://1drv.ms/10sWCCC). The add-on will have to be installed on any computer opening the workbook.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to pull in the data with the other workbooks closed. VLOOKUP will do this, I just don't know if you can use a cell ref (value) within the Table array of the VLOOKUP.

Comment: Thanks for the info on MoreFunc, does this allow me to pull in the data without the workbooks being open?

Comment: @Stuart - When you reply to another user *who did not start the thread that you are in* you need to use the @ symbol like I did at the beginning of this comment. That way they will be notified that you have responded. Regarding your question on `INDIRECT.EXT`, suggest you try [here](http://letmebingthatforyou.com/?q=INDIRECT.EXT) for more information.

Comment: @Jeeped - Thanks for your help, will look at info on MoreFunc and INDIRECT.EXT

Comment: @Jeeped - Unfortunately does not do what it 'says on the tin!' Should work as it accepts the formula I need but will not pull in the data from a closed workbook. If you CTRL+ALT+F9 when the other workbooks are closed it returns #REF! Have tried on both Excel 2007 & 2010 with the same results on both.